# Haskell: How to read in a series of Floats, and then write them into a list in Haskell with IO.

Tags: haskell

Basically what I am trying to do is have the user input a series of floats, and only stop them when the float they enter is bigger/smaller than an original float.

For example, calling a function "biggerThan 10", would then let the user input values. I know how to read the values, but don't know how to add them to a list so I can compare them to 10, in this case.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In a question here, you should include the exact code you have tried, and state what didn’t work, including the text of any error messages you received; otherwise the question is likely to be closed as too broad or not showing your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Her is sample:

```
main = do
         vs <- biggerThan 10
         print $ vs


biggerThan :: Int -> IO [Int]
biggerThan x = do
                 v <- readLn
                 if v > x then return [v]
                          else do
                                 vx <- biggerThan x  
                                 return $ v : vx
```

It works with `Int` but you can easily fix that.

Also it expect that each number is in separate line.

Comment: Just for OP’s reference: the pattern `do { x <- m; return $ f x }` is commonly written like `f <$> m` (using `<$>` = `fmap`), and this kind of recursive loop is often written with a helper function to avoid repeating all the parameters, like: `biggerThan x = loop where loop = do { v <- readLn; if v > x then pure [v] else (v :) <$> loop }`

Comment: @JonPurdy I'm not that good :) I tried to find something `IO a -> (a -> Bool) -> IO [a]` in hoogle, but surprisingly there nothing like it.